# VS2019 Suddenly giving 401.2 - Unauthorized on any project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, authentication

Suddenly Visual Studio 2019 is asking me to login when I run any of my projects.

I have tried deleting temp folders, changing ports and creating new virtual directories, changing the project properties of the authentication and authorization, and I have tried deleting the web.config to <deny users=?" />.

I also tried creating a new project and firing it off to check, and it also is looking for login credentials.

What might have happened, and what else should I check?